# How to populate a UITableView from NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

For this question I have seen couple of examples but in my case there is a major difference. I have a class `LTModel`, which is container of another class called `LTChallenge`:

Here is `LTModel`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "LTChallenge.h"

@interface LTModel : NSObject

@property   NSMutableArray  *challenges;
-(int) numberOfChallenges;
-(void) addChallenge:(NSString *) challengeName;
-(LTChallenge*) challengeAtIndex:(NSInteger) index;
@end
```

Here is `LTChallenge`:

```
@interface LTChallenge : NSObject

@property   NSString *name;
@property   NSMutableArray *times;
- (instancetype)init:(NSString *)challengeName;
- (void) addObject:(LTTime *) time;
@end
```

And now in my `UITableViewController` I am trying to fill up my table with the name of challenges. First I give them value:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];   
    //Instantiate
    lapTimerModel = [[LTModel alloc] init];
    [lapTimerModel addChallenge:@"Clap 20 times"];
    [lapTimerModel addChallenge:@"Say the alphabet"];
    [lapTimerModel addChallenge:@"100 Meter Sprint Challenge"];
    [lapTimerModel addChallenge:@"Read the IOS al spec challenge"];
}
```

And finally here I am populating the table where I need name of the challenges:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [lapTimerModel numberOfChallenges];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [lapTimerModel challengeAtIndex]; //???? Maybe in this line I need challenges array in LTModel, I used this but did not work

// cell.textLabel.text = [lapTimerModel.challenges objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

How to use `objectAtIndex:indexPath.row` in the line that I marked with question marks? Appreciate any suggestion.

**Edit**

Here is implementation of `challengeAtIndex`

```
-(LTChallenge*) challengeAtIndex : (NSInteger) index{

    return [_challenges objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Challenge is not an NSString. And you need to assign NSString to cell.textLabel.text:

```
LTChallenge *challenge = [lapTimerModel challengeAtIndex:indexpath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = challenge.name;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added your code but still it does not work. I have added implementation of challengeAtIndex as I am suspected to. Please let me know if something is wrong with that?

Comment: @Bernard, it seems to be ok. Mistake can be somewhere else. Have you tried to set breakpoint inside -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: and check if you get correct challenge object?